# Remote access to Hypertable from C++

Tags: c++, windows, hypertable

I have sucessfully installed Hypertable on top of Hadoop on a small cluster of Ubunto servers. At this point the only way to access the Hypertable is via the 'ht shell' command on one of the HT servers.

Thats all very interesting, but now I want to access the hypertable database from a PC thats not part of the cluster. Preferably from C++ - preferably on a Windows box.

It looks like I need a Vistual Studio compatible build of libHypertable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the mailing list, if you use the Thrift interface, you only need Client.h, ThriftHelper.* and gen-cpp/* from the src/cc/ThriftBroker directory to build a VS project. Native client would need more than libHypertable.a and is currently not yet ported to Windows. BTW, there are reports on the mailing lists that C# works fine via the thrift interface.

Comment: ah, so thrift can (and is) the recommended way to interop to Hypertable from windows? I'll investigate that then.